# Using a datagridview to display access records in realtime?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

Nothing too advanced in terms of which records. I am just looking to display all records from an access database table in a datagridview but in real-time as they are modified/added/deleted/etc.

As part of an inventory management program I am writing in vb.net (visual studio 2017) (Microsoft access 2010) I have a monitoring form that has all the info from my database in separate datagridviews (one for each table in the database). I'm running into a few issues however. First of all I cannot find a way to refresh the datagridviews when a record is changed. For example, if a quantity of a certain product is changed I want that to be reflected in the monitoring form. This software will be run on multiple computers simultaneously and I'm not sure of the best way to be able to accomplish this if say I am monitoring the inventory and a computer in the stockroom updates the quantity. If I want MY monitoring window to show the changes how would I go about doing that?

The next problem I have been facing is that when the datagridview is refreshed by calling the "fill" query of the tableadapter linked to the datagridview the list scrolls all the way to the top and the users position is lost. is there a way to keep the users position in the list? The way I am updating all the lists now is by running a query on the database to count the number of records and comparing it to the datagridview rowcount. If it is the same then it does nothing but if they are different then I refresh the datagridview.

If there is a way to just display the information from an access table in a datagridview in real-time that could solve at least the first of my problems. It may be wishful thinking but I could not find any information on how to do it yet.

I can provide any additional information if needed.

Comment: Access is suboptimal for this sort of thing, but it is simple enough to refresh (a true refresh) the data using a dataadapter.  The trick is being notified when a/the table has changed, and perhaps HOW (Insert, update, delete).  Some DBs have a class/tool for this, but it is not difficult to write your own.  Since access doesnt have stored procedures, its difficult to bootstrap that.

Comment: There is no magic. You would need to periodically poll each table for changes as it sounds like you are doing. However, you are only checking for added records. If you want changes, you should add a EditDate field to each table and update with each edit. Then instead of polling for record cound, poll for latest EditDate.

Comment: Well it sounds like what I was afraid of. Ideally I would like an easier way to check for updates but if there isn't one I'll have to try out what you suggested @AVG. I'm still open to other suggestions if anyone else weighs in with a different solution. I am still looking for a solution to the problem of the datagridview automatically scrolling when refreshed.

Comment: I would suggest posting a new question specifically aimed at the grid and .NET as it doesn't matter the source of the data. I would think that you would need to save the users' position before the refresh and return to it after the refresh.